# Select 2 Column with Different Conditions

Tags: mysql, join, derived-table

I need to create a query that give me completed and unpaid transaction in 2019 grouped weekly. I already create the query to generate the completed transaction, but I stuck when try to combine the unpaid transaction query into the completed transaction query

This is the query for completed transaction

```
SELECT WEEK(A.plat_create_time, 1) AS 'Week Create Time',
       COUNT(t1.lp_sign_time) AS 'Completed Order'
FROM deli_order A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT order_code, code, lp_sign_time
    FROM pg_send_package 
    UNION
    SELECT D.order_code, D.oms_code, C.cm_sign_time
    FROM pg_package C
    INNER JOIN pg_order D ON C.pg_order_id = D.id
) t1 ON t1.order_code = A.order_code
        AND t1.code = A.code
        AND YEAR(A.plat_create_time) = 2019
WHERE (YEAR(A.plat_create_time) = 2019) AND A.status = 6 AND t1.lp_sign_time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY WEEK(A.plat_create_time, 1);
```

And its generate something like this

```
Week | Completed Order
1         886
2         734
3         868
4         1000
```

And this is the query that I already try to generate both completed and unpaid transaction

```
SELECT WEEK(A.plat_create_time, 1) AS 'Week Create Time',
       COUNT(t1.lp_sign_time) AS 'Completed Order',
       COUNT(t2.plat_create_time) AS 'Unpaid Order'
FROM deli_order A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT order_code, code, lp_sign_time
    FROM pg_send_package 
    UNION
    SELECT D.order_code, D.oms_code, C.cm_sign_time
    FROM pg_package C
    INNER JOIN pg_order D ON C.pg_order_id = D.id
) t1 ON t1.order_code = A.order_code
        AND t1.code = A.code
        AND YEAR(A.plat_create_time) = 2019
LEFT JOIN
(   
    SELECT order_code, WEEK(plat_create_time,1) AS 'Create Time'
    FROM deli_order
    WHERE pay_state = 0 AND (YEAR(plat_create_time) = 2019)
) t2 ON t2.order_code = A.order_code
WHERE (YEAR(A.plat_create_time) = 2019) AND A.status = 6 AND t1.lp_sign_time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY WEEK(A.plat_create_time, 1);
```

but when I execute it, MySQL always give error message 'Unknown column 't2.plat_create_time' in field list'. My expected result is something like this

```
Week | Completed Order | Unpaid Order
1         886              51
2         734              42
3         868              40
4         1000             31
```

What should I change in my query?

Comment: The alias in `t2`, `'Create Time'`, is different from the column name in the `SELECT` clause of the outermost query.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I already remove the alias but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
SELECT order_code, WEEK(plat_create_time,1) AS 'Create Time'
```

to:

```
SELECT order_code, WEEK(plat_create_time,1) AS 'Create Time', plat_create_time
```